# Is there a way to visualize a time series data frame on Altair where variables are headers?

Tags: python, altair

I have to following data frame, that I want to visualize as a simple time series chart, but I can't find the way to plot it since my variables are in the header. Do you guys have any idea of how can I solve this?

This is my data frame:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have what the Altair docs call *wide-form data*; Altair works best with *long-form data*. To work with your wide-form data, you can either preprocess the data and reshape it using the [`melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) function in Pandas, or you can transform it in the renderer using [`transform_fold()`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/fold.html#user-guide-fold-transform) within the Altair chart specification.

For more information and some examples, see [Specifying Data in Altair: Long-form vs. Wide-form data](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data).

Comment: This is indeed very useful, thank you Jake!